# BOOTCAMP WINDOWS INSTALL STORAGE

Tags: mac, ssd, boot-camp

I recently used bootcamp assistant to install windows on my MacBook Air 2015. I had no intention of keeping macos alongside windows so I cleared the mac partition from disk utility in recovery mode and added back the partition with windows. My laptop has a 128gigs ssd. When I used macos, the usable size was 121gigs but now in windows, it is only 112gigs. What happened to the 9 gigs :P. I hope I can get it back. I checked if there were any other partitions in disk utility but there was only 1 which would be used for macos recovery and deleting it would mean problems however this partition only used 1-2gigs and was always there from the start. How can I get my 9 gigs back. Help please :D. I also tried the windows disk troubleshooter.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my storage space was the same! It was only the format windows uses. Windows uses GiBs and macos uses GB.